# What points should be included in SOP if the target program is industry focused and not researched focused?

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose, industry

I'm applying for MS in US, and for every university I'm making a tailored made SOP. I was applying for a program, which is industry focused and not research focused. And I am not sure what should be included in the SOP regarding that, as for research focused program we can include our research experience, and we can also check if the program fits our research interests, but what should we include for industry focused program?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some stuffs, could which be deserving to be taken into account:

- Explain about the expected contribution of this program to pave your
  way for the future professional career.
- Elaborate on any related working experience to the concept of the 
  program.
- Illustrate the intriguing points, corresponding to the program, have which stimulated you to pursue it.
- Pinpoint any presentation within the technical workshops around the     program's subject or any research-based experience, to depict your 
  related coherent background.
- Mention your potential ideas to commence a business, based on the
  acquired technical and professional skills, stemming from the
  program.
- ...